# Shellscript to autologin with help of expect

Tags: linux, shell, unix, expect

**script 1**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect
spawn sftp user@10.xx.xxx.xx
expect \"password\"
send \"pass\r\"
interact
send \"lls\r\"
```

**script 2**

```
#!/bin/bash

expect -c "
spawn sftp user@10.xx.xxx.xx
expect \"password\"
send \"pass\r\"
interact
send \"lls\r\"
"
```

I have installed TCL/TK,expect. 
script1 stops at password prompt itself.
script2 stops after successful login like

```
spawn sftp user@10.xx.xxx.xx
user@10.xx.xxx.xx's password:
Connected to 10.xx.xxx.xx.
sftp>
```

My next commands(say i have `lcd /home/usr/tmp ,mget *.*` )
 to transfer the files are not getting executed as part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `interact` has been called, the control is returned from the script to the user, so that you can type commands manually. Thus, any other command will not be called automatically.

Instead executing `interact` you should add another `expect` statement waiting for the sftp prompt (`sftp>`) and issue your desired command afterwards.

Comment: expect \"sftp>\"
send \"lls\r\"
I just added these two lines to script2 after removing interact. But the script does login and exit immediately after that without executing the cmds.Thanks

Comment: The `lls` command is being sent and your script quits without waiting for the result. You have to add another expect statement in order to wait for the result of the previous command.